# Selenium : xpath following-sibling where siblings have more children

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath, xpath-2.0

I hope I describe my problem/question in a comprehensible way.

I have and html that looks like this:

```html
<div class="class-div">
 <label class="class-label">
  <span class="class-span">AAAA</span>
 </label>
 <div class="class-div-a">
  <textarea class="class-textarea">
  </textarea>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="class-div">
 <label class="class-label">
  <span class="class-span">BBBB</span>
 </label>
 <div class="class-div-a">
  <textarea class="class-textarea">
  </textarea>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want the Xpath for the TextArea where the value of the Label is AAAA to populate it with a value in Selenium.

So somelike like this...

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(
    By.XPath("//div[@class='class-div']/label[@class='class-label'][span[@class='class-span' and text()='AAAA']]/following-sibling::div[@class='class-div-a']/textarea[@class='class-textarea']"))).SendKeys(valueTextArea);
```

Comment: This looks like correct `XPath`. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Selenium doesn't "see" the textarea. I get a timeout exception.

Answer (score 2):

Problem could be in this waiter condition, `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible`

The thing is that your `<textarea>` is not 'visible' in selenium context, visibility means that element is present in DOM (which is true) and it's size is greater then 0px which could be false for your `<textarea>` element. In java you would use `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElement()` instead of `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElement()`, not sure how it goes in C# but you get the picture.

Try and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: I tested this out real quick and I think you are correct. Using page factory model of:          [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//label/span[text()='AAAA']/ancestor::div[@class='class-div']//textarea")]
        private readonly IWebElement _textAreaAAAA = null;  and creating a method to type a value into the AAAA field worked fine for me.

Comment: @acikojevic, the problem is definitely not lying with the `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible`. The reason why I say this, is because the moment I change my xpath to explicitly look for the id attribute of `<textarea>` (which I don't want to do) then the `<textarea>`  is visible to selenium.

Comment: Rico what happens if you run it in debug mode and step through it and use driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//label/span[text()='AAAA']/ancestor::div[@class='class-div‌​']//textarea")).SendKeys("abcde");

Answer (score 0):

Let me quickly rephrase the question to make sure I understand, you need an xpath to find the textbox associated with the label where the text is `AAAA`.

You'll have to go back up the tree in this case, here are a couple of ways I might do that, although your xpath looks correct:

Using ancestor to be clear about which element you're moving up to (better IMO)

```
By.XPath("//label/span[text()='AAAA']/ancestor::div[@class='class-div']//textarea");
```

Or just moving back up the tree with `..`

```
By.XPath("//label/span[text()='AAAA']/../../..//textarea");
```

If your xpath exists, use asikojevics answer. The C# method is `ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By)`

****UPDATE****

Based on your comment of a trailing space after the text value, here is another xpath that should find the textarea in that case, using `contains` instead of `text()=`.

```
By.XPath("//label/span[contains(text(),'AAAA')]/ancestor::div[@class='class-div']//textarea");
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like your xpath is fine after taking a second look... not sure what's wrong with yours. It uses some methods I'm not use to so I had to look a little closer, but it seems to be fine. I think @acikojevic might be on the right track

Comment: You are right. My Xpath is indeed correct. The problem was that in my original html code there was a space (which I overlooked) after the text value of my `<span>` element. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you found the issue! For what it's worth you can deal with random leading or trailing spaces by using `[contains(text(),'AAAA')]` in your xpaths if necessary.